# How are page tables organised?

Tags: paging

I understand that each process has its own virtual address space along with its own page table for this virtual address space which maps virtual addresses to pages in frames in physical memory.

My question is how does the system ensure that different processes' page tables do not overlap. I.e. when a process requires a new page to be created in physical memory, how does it decide where to place it?

The accompanying question here is: is there a overarching system-wide page table? Or are the exclusively per-process page tables only?

Comment: Page tables can overlap when you use shared memory.

Comment: Each physical memory page has a flag that indicates whether it's in use in any page table, or a pointer to a linked list of PTEs that use it. The specifics will depend on the architecture.

Comment: There's also likely to be a system-wide list of unused physical memory pages, to make finding an unused page fast.

Comment: I'm sure the nitty gritty details are covered in any operating systems textbook.

Comment: Russinovich's "Windows Internals" book has a good explanation of how this works in Windows (of course). Specifically, the "Address Translation" section of the "Memory Management" chapter.  The neighboring sections in that chapter are also helpful.